# GROUP_CONCAT in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, group-concat

I am having data like this

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 E
2 F
3 G
3 H
3 I
3 J
3 K
```

by using this query

```
select ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id,Name 
from ABSTRACTS_ITEM , ABSTRACT_AUTHOR , AUTHORS_ABSTRACT
where
ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID
and
ABSTRACT_AUTHOR._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID
```

Now, I want to show data like this

```
1 A,B,C,D
2 EF
```

and so on..I also know it can achieve by `GROUP_CONCAT` function. So, I tried with this

```
SELECT ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id,
GROUP_CONCAT(ABSTRACT_AUTHOR.NAME) FROM
(select ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id,
Name
from
ABSTRACTS_ITEM , ABSTRACT_AUTHOR , AUTHORS_ABSTRACT
where
ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID
and
ABSTRACT_AUTHOR._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID)
```

But, It shows me error. So, what I am doing wrong here. What are the right procedure to achieve that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY` clause when you are using aggregate function. Also use `JOIN` to join tables.

So try this:

```
SELECT AI._id, GROUP_CONCAT(Name) AS GroupedName
  FROM ABSTRACTS_ITEM AI 
  JOIN AUTHORS_ABSTRACT AAB ON AI.ID = AAB.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID
  JOIN ABSTRACT_AUTHOR AAU ON AAU._id = AAB.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID
 GROUP BY tbl._id;
```

###### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/495113/1)

---

What you were trying was almost correct. You just needed to add `GROUP BY` clause at the end. But the first one is better.

```
SELECT ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) 
FROM
    (select ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id AS ID,
     Name
     from
    ABSTRACTS_ITEM , ABSTRACT_AUTHOR , AUTHORS_ABSTRACT
    where
    ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID
    and
    ABSTRACT_AUTHOR._id = AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer to this closed question (it has a good showcase in it). [SQL group results by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73138899/sql-group-results-by-row)

You must add an Aggregate Function to your selected field.
The one you want is: **GROUP_CONCAT**
with a custom **SEPARATOR** ', '

See related MySQL Documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Your Select Query would look like this:

```
SELECT id_place, placename, GROUP_CONCAT(plant_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'plantnames'
FROM BLOOM
JOIN PLACE ON id_place = fk_place
JOIN PLANT ON id_plant = fk_plant
GROUP BY id_place, placename;
```

Then you get your desired output:

| id_place | placename | plantnames |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New York | orchid, tulip |
| 2 | London | rosebush, orchid, tulip |
| 3 | Paris | rosebush, lily, violet |

Here is a DB Fiddle to check this out (MySQL 8.0):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSU7G4kKEaxsLMNweAtLSA/2

Comment: MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT is not compatible with SQLite's version