# How to query multiple values from a joined table in a select statment?

Tags: sql, spatialite

I’ve the following tables in a spatialite database:

This tables are filled as follows:

```
boden_verd:   
boden_verd_ID,boden_verd   
1,value1   
2,value2   
3,value3   

baumkataster:   
baum_ID, boden_verd      
1,{2}   
2,{1,3}   
3,{1,2,3}
```

What I need ist the following:

```
baum_ID,boden_verd   
1,{value2}   
2,{value3,value3}   
3,{value1,value2,value3}
```

I found a code-example (already adapted for my needs) for a similar problem but it returns an error and I don't realy know whrer I'am wrong:

```
SELECT baumkataster.baum_ID AS baum_ID,

stuff((select  DISTINCT  ', ' +  boden_verd.boden_verd
             from boden_verd
             WHERE ','+baumkataster.boden_verd+',' LIKE '%,'+boden_verd.boden_verd_ID+',%'
             for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '' )  AS boden_verd 

FROM baumkataster;
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your answers!!
Patrick

Comment: What error does it return? Your WHERE clause is unlikely to work for any SQL dbms, and it's open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It returns a syntax error near "for"

Comment: Are you using SQLite? If yes you are looking for `group_concat()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778844/group-concat-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite's SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) doesn't support any syntax like "for xml path()".

In a SQL database, you should expect to store values like this

```
baumkataster:   
baum_ID  boden_verd      
1        2
2        1
2        3
3        1
3        2
3        3
```

or like this.

```
baumkataster:   
baum_ID  boden_verd      
1        value2   
2        value3
2        value3
3        value1
3        value2
3        value3
```

Exceptions to this are relatively rare. (And supported by a dbms that provides xml functions or array functions.)