# Combining the many side of a many-to-one relationship into one field?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Two tables: `books` and `authors`. A book can have many authors, as in the case of a short story anthology.

## books

```
id    |    title
--------------------
1        The Time Machine Did It
2        Snakes in Suits
3        Ghost in the Wires
```

## authors

```
id    |    name
------------------------
1        Stephen King
2        John Swartzwelder
3        Robert D. Hare
4        Kevin Mitnick
5        William L. Simon
6        Steve Wozniak
7        Paul Babiak
```

## books_authors_link

```
book_id    |    authors_id
---------------------------
1                2
2                3
2                7
3                4
3                5
3                6
```

What I'd like to do is return a table where each row is a book, and the 'authors' field is a comma-separated list of all authors, eg

## query results

```
title                    |    authors
---------------------------------
The Time Machine Did It    John Swartzwelder
Snakes in Suits            Robert D. Hare, Paul Babiak
Ghost in the Wires         Kevin Mitnick, William L. Simon, Steve Wozniak
```

I've been playing around with `GROUP BY` and concatenation functions, and I know the answer is there somewhere, but I just can't quite figure it out. I can do it by juggling arrays and string joins around in my program itself but that's not the elegant solution I'm looking for. A tip here would be appreciated.

I'm using SQLite 3 if it's system-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join both tables, group by book and apply a `group_concat` on the author namecolumn.

The official documentation of the function is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

And [here´s another example I´ve found in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778844/group-concat-in-sqlite)