# Selecting Multiple ID's in one Select

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-concat

I have a Database with entries that have to be grouped togethe

```
id | Name    | Surname | Time
1  | Michael | Kane    | 3
2  | Torben  | Dane    | 4
3  | Dinge   | Chain   | 5
4  | Django  | Fain    | 5
5  | Juliett | Bravo   | 6
6  | Django  | Fain    | 7
7  | Django  | Fain    | 3
8  | Django  | Fain    | 4
9  | Dinge   | Chain   | 4
10 | Torben  | Dane    | 4
```

Now I want to group the items while maintaing all Id's. I'm comming close with the following query but I am lossing my ids

```
SELECT id, Name, Surname, sum(Time) from Names group by(Name)
```

The Result of the Query is

```
 id | Name    | Surname | Time 
 9  | Dinge   | Chain   | 9
 8  | Django  | Fain    | 19
 5  | Juliett | Bravo   | 6
 1  | Michael | Kane    | 3
 10 | Torben  | Dane    | 8
```

while I would need all ids like this

```
 ids    | Name    | Surname | Time 
 3,9    | Dinge   | Chain   | 9
 4,6,78 | Django  | Fain    | 19
 5      | Juliett | Bravo   | 6
 1      | Michael | Kane    | 3
 2,10   | Torben  | Dane    | 8
```

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: What are you going to do with the "ids" column?

Comment: I need them because i want to update them. Mark the line with the id as processed for example

Comment: That's what puzzles me. If you need them for processing later, why aggregate them like that? Query for the rows by "time" and process them. ?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create a bigger headache for yourself down the line.

Comment: The ids will not be processed emediately. Later it will be decided how the lines with the id will be updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GROUP\_CONCAT in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778844/group-concat-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this using `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(id, ',') as ids, name, surname, sum(time) as time
from table t
group by name, surname;
```

Just don't store the results back in the database.  Comma-separated values are useful for returning results, but it is the wrong format for storing data in the database.

Comment: group_concat(id) is sufficient. the rest was not allowed but you got me there thx