# combine field values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data structure in MySQL database:

```
{
date: text
name: text
}
```

and a data set:

```
"2016-01-01" "a1"
"2016-01-02" "a2"
"2016-01-02" "a3"
"2016-01-03" "a4"
```

I would like to combine "name" field, if the "date" is a same in different rows. So at the end to have something like:

```
"2016-01-01" "a1"
"2016-01-02" "a2, a3"
"2016-01-03" "a4"
```

Of course I could iterate over results-array and build a new structure, like this one, programmatically.. but maybe its a faster way to do this directly in SQL Query?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using. Generally it is called as `Group Concat`

Comment: SQLITE @ android devices. and MySQL server

Comment: Then why have you mentioned `MySQL` database in first line

Comment: Mainly SQLITE, plus Mysql at centos server

Comment: Also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering)

Comment: In `Mysql` you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` in-built function

Comment: Duplicate of SQLite here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778844/group-concat-in-sqlite