# Unnest (or similar) in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-in

I'd like to return multiple rows as a single row to be handled by an Android Cursor Adapter.

I currently have a table with a date column and I'd like to return, as a single row, all the rows that have the same date.

Consider the following table:

```
     ID |   Name   |   Date
 -------------------------------
      1 |  'Mark'  | '08/06/15'
      2 |  'Peter' | '08/06/15'
      3 |  'Henry' | '08/06/15'
      4 |  'Bob'   | '17/04/16'
      5 |  'Tony'  | '23/08/13'
      6 |  'Tim'   | '17/04/16'
```

I'd like to query the results as follows:

```
         Date    |       Names
    ------------------------------------
      '08/06/15' | 'Mark, Peter, Henry'
      '17/04/16' | 'Bob, Tim'
      '23/08/13' | 'Tony'
```

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18779034/2271421) I was able to obtain the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.Name ) AS Names
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```

However, since all the data is from the same table, and I know the dates to query in advance, I was hoping to use `JOIN` with an inputted array and have SQLite parse it (ie. like unnest in Postgres) as if it came from an actual table.

The array would be something like:

```
['08/06/15', '17/04/16', '23/08/13', '09/08/18']
```

This can probably also be done by nesting SQL queries, but I'd like an optimized solution if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has no array type.

The simplest way would be to use the [IN operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op):

```
SELECT ID, group_concat(Name) AS Names
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date IN ('08/06/15', '17/04/16', '23/08/13', '09/08/18')
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you really want to use a join, you can construct a virtual table with a [VALUES clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#values) (in Android Jelly Bean or later), or a compound query:

```
SELECT ID, group_concat(Name) AS Names
FROM MyTable
JOIN (VALUES('08/06/15'), ('17/04/16'), ('23/08/13'), ('09/08/18'))
  ON Date = column1
GROUP BY ID;
```

```
SELECT ID, group_concat(Name) AS Names
FROM MyTable
JOIN (SELECT '08/06/15' AS Date UNION ALL
      SELECT '17/04/16'         UNION ALL
      SELECT '23/08/13'         UNION ALL
      SELECT '09/08/18'                  ) USING (Date)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you! You're perfectly right, IN suited my needs quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT Date, group_concat(Name) AS Names
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Somewhat, yes. But I also needed to specify the Dates.